# Python: Can I use the AND operator in an array index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, and-operator

I have a list of values, x, and y:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [1, 3, 5, 8, 44, 8,0]
```

Which I convert to arrays:

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
```

When I try to print the corresponding y-values for a specified range of x, say x < 5, I get the correct output:

```
y_new = y[x < 5]
print(y_new)

Output: [1 3 5 8]
```

However, when I try to retrieve the values of y for 1 < x < 5, I get the following error:

```
y_1_5 = y[1 < x < 5]
y_15 = y[x > 1 and x < 5]
print(y_1_5)
print(y_15)

Ouput: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How do I fix this error because I want to print values of y for 1 < x < 5?
Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `1 < x & x < 5`

Comment: Except it needs to be `(1 < x) & (x < 5)`, because of how the precedence works.